# What determines whether a mobile will hang in stable or unstable equilibrium?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, equilibrium

Asking for a friend trying to make a Calder-style hanging mobile: https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+calder&tbm=isch

I understand torque just well enough to get it to balance (theoretically). But, what determines whether perturbations to the balance result in restorative torque (which would make the mobile stably balanced, right...?) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centre of mass exactly below the point of suspension is the equilibrium position.  For a small displacement from the equilibrium position you need to have a restoring torque back toward the equilibrium position.  Put another way you want the potential energy vs displacement graph around the equilibrium position to exhibit a minimum.

Nice description here of what to do in practice $\Rightarrow$ http://www.marcomahler.com/how-to-make-mobiles/ and many other sites on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

At every joint you need the center of mass of the suspended material to be below the support.  For mobiles, that is fairly natural.